# Is there a way to fade in and fade out the supersized loader div, #supersized-loader?

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout, supersized

I have a very limited knowledge of working with jquery and can usually muddle through, but I have a project where the client would like the 'preloading' image to fade in and fade out before the supersized slideshow sequence begins.  I see the line in the 3.2.7 js file that initializes and removes the div, but can I modify this to put a fadeIn and fadeOut of about 1.5 seconds each?

```
$('#supersized-loader').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to google it?

http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

```
// To fade in
$('#supersized-loader').fadeIn();

// To fade out
$('#supersized-loader').fadeOut();

// Chain commands...
$('#supersized-loader').hide().fadeIn().fadeOut().remove();

// ...or possibly
$('#supersized-loader').hide().fadeIn().fadeOut(function(){
    // Remove the layer.
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: Does `.remove` use the animation queue?  If not, you have to use it in the callback instead.